# Is freemarker prepared for too big CSV files?

Tags: freemarker

currently i am using freemarker to read data from a CSV template and generate a java class that loads that data.
The problem is that the CSV file is getting more and more entries regularly and now java compilation fails with error "code too large" as the file generated exceeds the 64mb java size limit.
Does freemarker has something to protect against this? Like knowing the file being generated is becoming too big so it generates N java classes that complement each other?

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker is totally unaware of what's it generating. It just generates some text, as far as it's concerned.

The limitation I know of is 64K of byte code **per method** (not 64K of source code). Probably you should divide the generated code to methods. Like, for each 1000 CSV rows you generate a method, and then at the end you generate a method that calls all the previously generated methods.

Also, generating that much code, based on a CSV, is suspicious. Maybe you should load the data on runtime instead?